# Drawing back to transparent in actionscript

Tags: actionscript

When I have a movie clip, it starts out s transparent.
I can draw on this movie clip, producing essentially a transparent image.  That is, wherever I have not yet drawn, shows the layer below, and where I have drawn, it shows what I have just drawn.

Question is, how to "undraw" things in this movie clip, so  that I can see what is behind it.  I know I could erase the movie clip, but is there a way to un-draw parts of the movie clip to get it back to transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another movie clip as a mask. I think it's setMask() in MovieClip to set another movieclip as its mask. Then you can draw on the mask movieclip the areas you want to show. Unfortunately in AS2, you can only use vector shapes as masks.

Comment: Reason I'm asking is that I want to avoid adding another layer.

Comment: you don't need another layer (if you literally mean the layers in the IDE). You can add the mask dynamically so your MC has just the one base layer.

Comment: I'm doing everything under program code already.  I wanted to know if its possible to draw back to transparent, not add masks or layers.  I guess the answer is that its not possible.